# Running perl test in intellij: Can't load module PassEnv at

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, tdd

I want to created perl modules in intellij derived by Tests. I created following test in a new project as shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

done_testing();
```

But when i am trying to run the test (Shift+Alt+F10), it fails with below error

> Testing started at 10:51 ...
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/bin\perl.exe C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/prove.bat -PPassEnv --formatter TAP::Formatter::Camelcade --merge --recurse --jobs 1 D:/workspace/code/repo/Modules/ImageUtilities/ReaConverterTest.t
>   Can't load module PassEnv at C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/prove.bat line 26.
>  
>   Process finished with exit code 2

But when I run the test from the command line it works fine

```
$ perl -w ReaConverterTest.t
1..0
```

I see that there was an issue reported with intellij perl plugin(https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/issues/1966) but it is closed. Looks like it was fixed in 2019.1 Perl but I am clueless why it's failing for me.

Any idea on how to fix this?

PS: I am using Git-Bash to run Perl scripts, IntelliJ using strawberry Perl installation on windows as Perl interpreter.

---

## Update

When i run the script by adding "use PassEnv" it fails as there is no such module Searching from intellij also results in "no such module"

```
perl -w ReaConverter.t
Can't locate PassEnv.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PassEnv module) (@INC contain
s: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/sha
re/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at ReaConverter.
t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ReaConverter.t line 6.
```

Comment: What does `C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/prove.bat` look like? What happens if you `use PassEnv`?

Comment: The error says that `prove` can't find a module. It's not a big surprise that you don;t get the error when you don't use `prove`.

Comment: Please don't use two different builds of `perl` in the same question!

Comment: @JimGarrison I have updated the question with the information you need. I am not aware of this prove.bat script in strawberry Perl package. I am not able to decipher it too.

Comment: `prove.bat` embeds [this](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-Harness/source/bin/prove)

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -le"require Config; print $Config{archname}; require App::Prove; print App::Prove->VERSION"` (Adjust quotes to match your shell as necessary.)

Comment: perl -le"use Config; use App::Prove; print for $Config{archname}, App::Prove->VERSION"<br/>
`Can't locate TAP/Harness/Env.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TAP::Harness::Env module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Prove.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Prove.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`

Comment: I said using your Strawberry Perl. There's no point running these commands on a different `perl` than the one you want fixed. (PS - I also made a change to the command I'd like you to run)

Comment: `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe`

Comment: (It does seem that both of your Perl installations are messed up, though. How!?)

Comment: Ahh! I always have trouble with strawberry and git-bash on same windows env. I always struggle to use strawberry Perl uniformly. @ikegami I am still not sure if this problem is caused by Perl environment being messed up.

Comment: @ikegami Here is the output `$ /c/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl -le"use Config; use App::Prove; print for $Config{archname}, App::Prove->VERSION"
HASH(0x30ce350)
3.42`.

Comment: You appear to be using a `bash` or similar. You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes. Still, I got what I wanted.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `-PPassEnv` before. I thought things were messed up because it was trying to load a dependency, but it's not a dependency. Posting an answer in two secs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `-PPassEnv` option used, `prove` attempts to load App::Prove::Plugin::PassEnv. It hasn't been installed. Simply install the module.

Note: You want to install it using Strawberry Perl, so the following appears to be the appropriate command from your preferred shell:

```sh
/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm App::Prove::Plugin::PassEnv
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami Above module depends on  "ExtUtils::Manifest" . After installing that, It installed perfectly. `/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm  ExtUtils::Manifest  App::Prove::Plugin::PassEnv`. But when i run test again from IntelliJ, It fails for some other package(TAP::Formatter::Camelcade). But given your details comments, I may be able to take from this.

Comment: Bingo! After installing that last module, It worked. ```Testing started at 13:25 ...
C:/Strawberry/perl/bin\perl.exe C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/prove.bat -PPassEnv --formatter TAP::Formatter::Camelcade --merge --recurse --jobs 1 D:/workspace/code/ReaConverter.t
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: PASS```